# why not insert query is working in codeigniter when ever we use right syn.?

Tags: php, codeigniter, query-builder

why not  insert query is working whenever i am using right syn.,i have used this type syntax in my other function of same controller.

### code

```
$reviewData = $this->input->post('reviewData');
$id=1;
        $rdaraaa = array(
                       'id'      => $id,
                       'content' => $reviewData 
                       );

        $this->db->insert('reviews', $rdataaa);
```

please help me

Comment: You spelled the variable name wrong. The way to debug this is by trying to print it out right before you use it, and seeing if its value is what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable name is wrong.It should be

```
$this->db->insert('reviews', $rdaraaa);
```

You have given wrong array `$rdataaa` instead of `$rdaraaa`.And makesure that id,content are the column names in your table `reviews`.

Answer (score 0):

remove this code `print_r($rdaraaa); die;` and it should be
`$this->db->insert('reviews',$rdaraaa)`